# Always using Async in an ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I recently inherited an ASP.NET MVC project. In that project, the developer is using `async` *everywhere*. I'm trying to assess if its a good idea or not. Specifically, I'm reviewing the controller code at the moment.

In the controllers, the developer wrote the stuff like the following:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
  return View();
}
```

Is there any advantage to this instead of the traditional version:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View();
}
```

I could understand using `async` if `await` was used in the controller code. A lot of times, its not being used though. Is there any justification for this approach?

Comment: I this this [article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/25/measuring-the-performance-of-asynchronous-controllers/) summarizes what AsyncController are ment for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. That's not a good idea to use Async everywhere.

Regarding the missing await the compiler issues a warning when an `Async` method does not contain an `Await` operator. An Async method without an await will run synchronously, which makes the semantics incorrect.

For your specific example, the operation is simple and short running, and that's why using Async/Await does not bring any benefits, and it shouldn't be used, so you are perfectly fine using:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Async/Await should be used for controller methods that perform some kind of IO (e.g. Network requests, Database access etc.). If a controller method is doing CPU bound work (e.g. math. calculations), then using Async/Await can actually make performance worse, unless your measurements prove me wrong.

The old rule applies: **Measure twice, cut once**.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense to make action/method if there is no `await` anywhere in this method. Making method `async` means that "under the box" (by compiler) would be created state machine which makes a little overhead versus pure void version (really small overhead but if you have milion requests per second that can make a difference ;)). If you are scared that there could be await introduced soon (you better have good reason for "being scared") and you have a lot of code dependend on this method (for instance it's abstract class method/ it belongs to interface) you should keep method returning `Task<ActionResult>` but without marking it asynchronous. Example:

```
public Task<ActionResult> MyAction() {

    return Task.FromResult<ActionResult>(View());
}
```

This `Task.FromResult<T>` method returns completed task - which prevents compiler creating asynchronous state machine.

Back to your main question - seems like people who wrote this code didn't know what they're doing - marking method async doesn't mean that method works "asynchronously".